# Insert "\n" to each line of paragraphs

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a list product description stored in csv file. In order to post multiple products to my wordpress site by uploading csv template of wp, I need to format my product descripton to html formart like this:

```
\nMy product description para 1
\nMy product description para 2
\n
\nMy product description para 3
```

And this is my current text:

```
My product description para 1
My product description para 2

My product description para 3
```

I want to insert "\n" to the beginning of each paragraph in a product description.

And here is my attempt:

```
df=pd.read_csv('product_info_table.csv')
product_desc=df['product_desc']

#for item in product_desc:
#   print(item)

myword = "\n"
list_product_desc=[]  
for item in product_desc:
    new_item=""
    for line in item.splitlines():
        new_line="{}{}".format(myword, line)
        new_item=new_item+new_line
        #new_item=new_item+new_line+'\n'
    list_product_desc.append(new_item)


#print(list_product_desc)

results=list_product_desc
file=open("new_product_desc.csv",'w',encoding='utf-8')
for line in results:
    file.write(line)
    file.write('\n')
```

When I execute print(list_product_desc), I have reach somthing like this:

```
[\nMy product description para 1\nMy product description para 2\n\nMy product description para 3, \nMy product description para 1 for product 2\nMy product description para 2 for product 2\n\nMy product description para 3 for product 2,.....]
```

However I do not know how to save it to new csv file. My attempt in saving them to csv file as above is okay with a test list, for example ['item 1','item3','item m'] but failed for list_product_desc.

The csv file created by that code has text but very confused. It is not organized as the initial file (before adding '/n'). Each cell of csv (in excel) stores just one line instead of many paragraphs (full description of one product is stored in one cell in my initial file).

Any solution suggested to solve this problem? thanks alot

EDIT: Try to use dataframe.to_csv but also failed:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'new_product_desc':list_product_desc})
print(df2)#this step is good, the result as my expectation

df2.to_csv('mo_ta_sp_moi.csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
#df2.to_csv('mo_ta_sp_moi.csv.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

The result is a csv file with just a title 'new_product_desc' in cell A1
And this is a result of print(df2):

```
                                      new_product_desc
0    \npara descripton of product 1, ...
1    \npara 1 descrtion of product 2\npara 2 description of product 2...
....
229  \npara description of product 230...

[230 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Does your original CSV file contain only one column (the product description) or more ?

Comment: Have you tried to save the DataFrame with [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) ?

Comment: @Ralf: No, original CSV file has multiple columns but I used dataframe to extract just one column named product_desc. That column has multiple row, each row stored infomation of 1 product description (multiple paragraphs).

Comment: @Ralf: I've just tried to use df.to_csv but it failed. I added some words about this on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve and store the CSV file I use `pandas` in this example, and then use `.map()` to apply a text transformation function to the description column of the dataframe.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

def transform(s):
    return '\n' + s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    print()
    print('Original CSV')
    print(df.shape)
    print(df)

    df['desc'] = df['desc'].map(lambda x: transform(x))
    print()
    print('New CSV')
    print(df.shape)
    print(df)

    import csv
    df.to_csv('test_2.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

The output of the code:

```
Original CSV
(3, 3)
   num            desc  price
0    1          \nalfa     10
1    2  \nbeta1\nbeta2     13
2    3         \ngamma     85

New CSV
(3, 3)
   num              desc  price
0    1          \n\nalfa     10
1    2  \n\nbeta1\nbeta2     13
2    3         \n\ngamma     85
```

The input file **test.csv**:

```
"num","desc","price"
1,"
alfa",10
2,"
beta1
beta2",13
3,"
gamma",85
```

The output file **test_2.csv**:

```
"num","desc","price"
1,"

alfa",10
2,"

beta1
beta2",13
3,"

gamma",85
```

Comment: @Huynh of course you will have to implement the `transform()` function to fit your specific needs; I just added a mock implementation to show how the saving process works.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `products.csv` is your file containing

```
My product description para 1
My product description para 2

My product description para 3
```

This script should do the trick:

```py
with open('products.csv') as f:
    new_file = ''
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_file += '\\n' + line
        with open('new_products.csv', 'w') as nf:
            nf.write(new_file)
```

I just don't understand why you want the file to be a `.csv`, as you have only 1 column on each line. But if you really must have the `.csv` extension, this code will do it.

Comment: your script returns each line of product description into each line in csv file. That is not my expectation. In my orginal file, each product has a description stored in just one cell. And, that description has many paragraphs. And now I just want to add '\n' to front of each paragraph and ensure that each description is still stored in just one cell of csv file.

Comment: @Huynh You should have described what your constraints were, then. You don't mention that a product description can contain more than one paragraph nor your example indicates it.